# BitMap size exceeds VM budget Android

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, out-of-memory

I know there are many questions and answers about the topic but I have a very strange behavior I can't find in any of the many explanation for this very strange error.

The error happens in my app randomly when I rotate the screen passong from one activity to another and happens in the newly created activity at the line:

```
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
```

I've tried with a nice, heavy jpeg background and with a somple, light monocolor one but the result is the same.

I've tried to make a simple app with a button to switch between two activities and I can't reproduce the error.

I've tried to set a breakpoint before the incriminated line and with it there is no problem, just like if waiting made the app working.

I never use methods to load the Bitmap, I've no clue what's going on.

Thank you for your help, if you think I could add some useful info please let me know, I added all I do, I hope this is enough.

This is the logCat output:

```
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765): com.controller fatal error : Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.controller/pages.RicercaAllarmiPage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.controller/pages.RicercaAllarmiPage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3770)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at pages.RicercaAllarmiPage.drawRicercaAllarmi(RicercaAllarmiPage.java:112)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at pages.RicercaAllarmiPage.onCreate(RicercaAllarmiPage.java:94)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  ... 11 more
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  ... 20 more
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:588)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:563)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:426)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1981)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:653)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1992)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1940)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:286)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:120)
10-01 16:31:16.750: E/ACRA(12765):  ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling Bitmap in android is very big issue,
In Your case setting background resource ultimately leads to the bitmap only, internally,
So, My suggestion would be:

1. Reduce your Drawable to a reasonable size
2. Follow [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: But why I am not able to reproduce the error with a very simple app and the same Drawable/Background?

Comment: @LuigiTiburzi Probably this can be because of the heap size occupied by the application, In your simple app it must be very low to not to exceed the VM budget, Application which already has occupied almost all the heap available can exceed the VM budget...
Check out the heap occupied by your application in DDMS...

Comment: Excuse me, the last why :-), why if I use a very very simple background (monocolor) very very light the problem still persist? Why I have the problem only when rotating screen between activities transition and not if I don't rotate it? The space required should be the same...

Comment: Well... While rotating the screen the activity in recreated, excepting the case when handling config changes manually,still the cause of problem is not clear.
Are you keeping drawables in orientation wise folders?
 and Please show the logcat output. It could be helpful.

Comment: I was able not to recreate the activity onConfigChange. In the edit you'll find the logcat